# Can I use swscanf_s with Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Does Linux have a standard version of swscanf_s?
It is a security enhanced version of swscanf that Visual Studio supplies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These functions are part of standard C (see C11, chapter K.3.5), so any platform that supports the C11 version of the language must provide the `_s`-versions of the functions.

While it doesn't appear that GCC (4.6.2, with `-std=c1x`) currently implements this, it is to be expected in future releases.

Comment: Note that chapter K is an optional extension which a conforming compiler is not required to support...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Good call, I didn't realise it was "optional". Thanks!